# loop the value in excel

Tags: excel, vba

i have to loop the value and it has 3 column and 12 row

[image]

how to loop the value like in first take value from column 1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1 then take value from 1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2 then 1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,3 then 1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,1 then 1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2 then 1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,3 then 1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,3,1 and so on....
so how to loop this column to take value and put in another cell and do other stuff

i write sample code for loop

```
    Sub file()
Range("E13").Select

For a = 1 To 3
colno = a + 5
colletter = Split(Cells(1, colno).Address, "$")(1)
Value1 = Range("" & colletter & "13").Value

For b = 1 To 3
colno2 = b + 5
colletter2 = Split(Cells(1, colno2).Address, "$")(1)
Value2 = Range("" & colletter2 & "14").Value
For c = 1 To 3
colno3 = c + 5
colletter3 = Split(Cells(1, colno3).Address, "$")(1)
Value3 = Range("" & colletter3 & "15").Value
For d = 1 To 3
colno4 = d + 5
colletter4 = Split(Cells(1, colno4).Address, "$")(1)
Value4 = Range("" & colletter4 & "16").Value
For e = 1 To 3
colno5 = e + 5
colletter5 = Split(Cells(1, colno5).Address, "$")(1)
Value5 = Range("" & colletter5 & "17").Value
For f = 1 To 3
colno6 = f + 5
colletter6 = Split(Cells(1, colno6).Address, "$")(1)
Value6 = Range("" & colletter6 & "18").Value
For g = 1 To 3
colno7 = g + 5
colletter7 = Split(Cells(1, colno7).Address, "$")(1)
Value7 = Range("" & colletter7 & "19").Value
For h = 1 To 3
colno8 = h + 5
colletter8 = Split(Cells(1, colno8).Address, "$")(1)
Value8 = Range("" & colletter8 & "20").Value
For i = 1 To 3
colno9 = i + 5
colletter9 = Split(Cells(1, colno9).Address, "$")(1)
Value9 = Range("" & colletter9 & "21").Value
For j = 1 To 3
colno10 = j + 5
colletter10 = Split(Cells(1, colno10).Address, "$")(1)
Value10 = Range("" & colletter10 & "22").Value
For k = 1 To 3
colno11 = k + 5
colletter11 = Split(Cells(1, colno11).Address, "$")(1)
Value11 = Range("" & colletter11 & "23").Value
For l = 1 To 3
colno12 = l + 5
colletter12 = Split(Cells(1, colno12).Address, "$")(1)
Value12 = Range("" & colletter12 & "24").Value

Next l
Next k
Next j
Next i
Next h
Next g
Next f
Next e
Next d
Next c
Next b
Next a
End Sub
```

any idea how to optimized it?

Comment: What have you found in your research? Please include the code you have so far in your question.

Comment: I think it’s better if you explain what do you want to do with the values. Otherwise, reading them into an array and accessing them through their index/position would be more efficient

Comment: i want to add this value to another cell and after calculating final answers, answers are paste in another sheet

Comment: This seems highly unusual as far as looping goes, are you sure it needs to add those fields? What is the objective?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would work in base three (if there are three columns of data) to represent each selection as a number:

```
000000000000
000000000001
000000000002
000000000010
000000000011
000000000012
000000000020
000000000021
000000000022
```

and so on and extract the last digit, previous digit etc. to choose which number to select in each row. This is a more general method than using nested loops which are specific to a certain number of rows.

```
Option Explicit

Sub CountBase3()

    Dim R As Range

    Set R = Range("F2:H13")

    Dim Rows As Long, Columns As Long, Maxcount As Long

    Rows = R.Rows.Count()

    Columns = R.Columns.Count()

    Maxcount = Columns ^ Rows

    Debug.Print ("Maxcount=" & Maxcount)

    'Copy range to array

    Dim data As Variant

    data = R

    Dim counter As Long, row As Long, column As Long, counterShifted As Long

    Dim Values()

    ReDim Values(Rows)

    'Loop over selections - 531441 to find all the sets but just look at the first few for now

    For counter = 0 To 8

        counterShifted = counter

        For row = Rows To 1 Step -1

        'Get column from right hand digit of counter

        column = counterShifted Mod Columns + 1

        Values(row) = data(row, column)

        'Shift counter by dividing by number of columns (3)

        counterShifted = counterShifted \ Columns

        Next row

    'Display current selection

    Debug.Print ("Set " & counter + 1)

    For row = 1 To Rows

    Debug.Print (Values(row));

    Next row

    Debug.Print ("")

    Next counter

End Sub
```

Output

```
Maxcount=531441
Set 1
 700  500  500  500  450  400  400  450  300  250  200  100 
Set 2
 700  500  500  500  450  400  400  450  300  250  200  150 
Set 3
 700  500  500  500  450  400  400  450  300  250  200  200 
Set 4
 700  500  500  500  450  400  400  450  300  250  250  100 
Set 5
 700  500  500  500  450  400  400  450  300  250  250  150 
Set 6
 700  500  500  500  450  400  400  450  300  250  250  200 
Set 7
 700  500  500  500  450  400  400  450  300  250  300  100 
Set 8
 700  500  500  500  450  400  400  450  300  250  300  150 
Set 9
 700  500  500  500  450  400  400  450  300  250  300  200
```